# What is an alternative to calling a function in a constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor, load, onload, onload-event

I am calling a function in my constructor in my C# class. The constructor gets called at design time, so instead of calling my function there, I thought of adding the OnLoad event and call my function from there instead. However, since I am new to C#, I am not sure how to do this, since I read that the OnLoad is for forms and I don't see a couple of solutions working (Load is not being recognized). How can I achieve loading the function without calling it in the constructor?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `Load` is called by specific framework base types which know to call it.  Are you building something of that type?  Or are you just building a normal class?  Can you show a small example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @xxbbcc find the alternative, i.e. trying to find what I can do or how I can load the function in a way other than calling it from the constructor. E.g. <br/>

public class A { <br/>

public A() { method1(); } <br/>

private method1(string a=" ") { <br/>
}<br/>

Instead of the above, I want to load the method1 in an alternative way

Comment: @TusharGupta: Please put code in the question, not in comments.  It's much easier to read that way.  Aside from that, it's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Does calling the method from your constructor not work?  What indication do you have of a problem?  What are you trying to solve?

Comment: @David Calling the method from the constructor works, it does not have any issue. However, as mentioned in the question, I am looking for an alternative as I do not want to call the method from the constructor for better performance.

Comment: @TusharGupta: What "better performance"?  Performance sounds like a problem you're trying to solve.  Have you *measured* the performance of your current code?  Is there a bottleneck?  What makes you think that invoking a method from somewhere else is going to make that method run any faster?  It really sounds like there's no actual problem being addressed here, so it's still not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @xxbbcc It is known for code to be better placed in the OnLoad event.  The contructor gets called at design-time (when you open the control in Visual Studio), so no code should be added there that won’t be available at design-time. Since I am new to C#, I asked about if add the “OnLoad” event works and how so I can move the code there

Comment: @Unknown: So what happens when you place your code in the `OnLoad` event in your form?  How is that failing?  And why are you still refusing to *show an example* in your question of the code you're using?  If you're using a `Form` and want to put code in its `OnLoad` handler, put code there.  Or put it in the constructor.  Or somewhere else applicable.  It's still completely unclear what you're trying to do or what isn't working.

Comment: @David Please see from the question: Load is not recognized is mentioned as what happens when I use it; Mine is a class, not using or inheriting from Form; Please respond only if you have a clear understanding from what is in the question and an idea of any method by which this can be resolved

Comment: @David Please don't bother to waste your precious time on posts that you cannot understand..I don't know why it is so difficult to infer a simple example that is already provided...and do NOT use foul language at least on portals where people research, study and share useful knowledge!

Comment: @Unknown: What simple example?  If your simple example is that you have a class which doesn't have a `Load()` method, and you're trying to call a `Load()` method, then why do you expect that to work?  A method has to *be defined* before you can *call* it.  This is true in *every* programming language.  You can't invoke code that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Below's an example of how to implement the [Factory Pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=factory%20pattern) in order to create an instance of the class in question. The benefit here is that the `SpecialMethod` is called by your "API" and not the consumer of your "API." Ensuring `SpecialMethod` is always called; change behavior to suit your scenario ...

```
/* consumer (on your page load) */
var instance = SomeClass.GetInstance();

public class SomeClass
{
    /* prevent consumers from directly instantiating `SomeClass` */
    private SomeClass() {}

    public static SomeClass GetInstance()
    {
        var instance = new SomeClass();
        instance.SpecialMethod();
        return instance;
    };

    private void SpecialMethod()
    {
        /* Special stufff ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example... but I think a non-static method cannot be accessed in static context, if I'm not wrong?

Comment: yeah, just modded it. overlooked that. original example was more "pseudocode"